# How to use TF-IDF with visual bag of words using sift

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, classification

I use the same approach as this link: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/bag-of-visual-words-bag-of-features-9a2f7aec7866

As described in the link, TD IDF can be used to remove the less important "visual words" from the visual bag of words. However, after looking online it seems that TD-IDF is only implemented for text feature extraction. (For example, the sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer)

Is there an easy way to use the TF-IDF for image classification rather than text?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it's standard enough with images, but it's easy enough to calculate it yourself:

- For any "visual word", the Document Frequency (DF) is the number of images containing this "visual word" divided by the total number of images. The IDF is the inverse of this value.
- The "Term Frequency" (TF) of a "visual word" in a particular image is how many times the "word" appears in the image divided by the total number of "words" in this image.

Now just apply the formula: TFIDF = TF * log(IDF).

Alternatively you could represent each image as a pseudo-sentence with strings representing the visual words, and then use the standard `TfidfTransformer` on the set of pseudo-sentences. But it's probably more work for little advantage.